# How (if) can we connect a 2D "throat" piece of a wormhole to two hyperbolic 2D manifolds?

Tags: cosmology, metric-tensor, curvature, space, wormholes

This question wad closed on the mathematics site, as it lacked clarity. So I try my luck here. My question is cosmology-inspired.

Imagine two 2D hyperbolic manifolds. I connect them by a manifold like one sees pictured in images of a wormhole in 2D. Can we glue them together so the geodesics always diverge? I mean, we can view the wormhole structure as the inner part of a torus, and there lines starting out parallel, diverge (negative curvature). If it can be done, can we extend the result to 4D in a simple way?

We could use the pseudosphere as intermediate:

"In geometry, a pseudosphere is a surface with constant negative Gaussian curvature."

[image]

Which looks like a decoupled wormhole. We just have to paste the two 2D hyperbolic manifolds to the middle pieces, the mouths, and connect the thin outer pieces.